# CSS overflow property in table cells with firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

1.) This works in Chrome.

In Firefox, however, a django tables table that we are rendering on our site is not observing the overflow style.  From what I read, table cell elements may be a "per browser" decision because they aren't pure block elements (if I am understanding the standard correctly), but here's a picture of my problem.

[image: Overflow problem with table cells]

I've tried fussing with the max-width tag (to no effect other than the width changes but the overflow is still garbled into the next cell).  I could technically wrap the line (white-space), but we don't want huge table rows on the page.

The Mozilla developer page ([Overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)) says "In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap."  The height property doesn't seem to change this either. No other CSS property I've tried seems to have an effect.

I keep thinking that this is something Firefox may not support (i.e. table cells aren't "block-level"?), but I can't quite say that for certain.

EDIT: Here's the html. It's just a basic table produced by django tables. Please ignore the inline style I attempted which is commented out.

[image: HTML code]

EDIT: Here's inline code and a JSFiddle link at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<head>
<style>
<body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

th {
    padding: 8px;
}

td {
   padding: 8px;
}

td.content {
overflow-x: scroll;
max-width: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Other stuff</td><td class="content">A REALLY REALLY REALLY 
 REALLY LONG MESSAGE</td><td>Other stuff</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3zumhqy/3/)

Comment: If it's not readily evident, I want there to be a scroll bar there.

Comment: can you show us the html and css code with snippet?

Comment: I highlighted the relevant css in the picture but I'll add the html code for posterity.

Comment: You need to take html, css and js in question and make them into a snippet that we can interact with. Images of code are mostly useless.

Comment: Alright, I have a link to a jsfiddle now, it exhibits the same problem.  Works in Chrome, not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple code for you, i hope help you, tell me if this is what you want:

```css
.msg_list{
border:1px solid red;
}

.td-content{
border:1px solid blue;
max-height:100px;
max-width:100px;
}
  
.content{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: auto;
}

.content div{
 width:200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="msg_list">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-content">
         <div class="content">
           <div>One really really really really really long message</div>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you watch you can see in the **css** the class **.content** and his property **max-width**, i tested it in firefox, you can try it

Comment: I appreciate that, what I was looking for was one line of text with a scroll bar along the bottom using the css overflow property.

Comment: Ready, can you check it now

Comment: This works, in terms of css, and you couldn't have known that it is more difficult to get the table to render div tags within cells as part of django tables.  But I can do that with jquery, I suppose, although it's not ideal.  I will accept this answer.

Comment: Also, only need the outer div tag in the cell.